# Showing a function is a metric.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Theorem:
>   The function $d\left ( x,y \right )=min\left \{ \left \{ x-y \right \},1-\left | x-y \right | \right \}$ is a metric in [0,1].

The proof begins with "Notice that $0\leq \left | x-y \right |<1  \space so\space d\left ( x,y \right )$ is non-negative"

This is not at all clear to me.
[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What space are we considering? Is it $[0,1)$?

Comment: Metric must satisfy: 1) $d(x,y)\ge 0, \forall x,y$, 2) d(x,y)=d(y,x)$, 3) $d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$. If your function satisfies these then it's a metric.

Comment: @Sanderr Yes, in the closed interval [0,1] of a unit circle.

Comment: Are you sure both 0 and 1 are included? Because then $d(1,0)=0$ which means $d$ cannot be a metric.

Comment: Yes, 1 is included. Let me attached my notes.@Sanderr OP has been edited

Comment: Notice that in the notes it says that 0 and 1 have been identified with each other (think glued together) and by convention 1 is not in $S^1$, it is only with this convention followed that this is a metric because now we don't ever consider $d(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $1 \notin S_1$, we have $0 \leq |x-y| < 1$. In other words, both $|x-y| \geq 0$ and $|x-y|<1$ so that also $\min(|x-y|,1-|x-y|) \geq 0$. This is the non-negativity property. The other properties (see the definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) are also easily shown. Does this answer your question?

Comment: It might make it clearer if you say explicitly that this gives us that both $|x-y|>0$ and $1-|x-y|>0$, hence no matter which is smaller, $d(x,y)>0$.

Comment: I do not understand why we do not consider 1 in S1? This is my first class in Topology and analysis.

Comment: It's a convention used in your notes. The idea is that you glue the ends of a line (in this case $[0,1]$) together and call that a circle ($S_1$). So then $0$ and $1$ become the same point, and it is a convention to exclude $1$.

Comment: So intuitively, the circle is now an 'open' circle?

Comment: This is still the closed unit circle. It is just that since $0$ and $1$ become the same point by gluing them together, you choose to call that point $0$ and say that $1 \notin S_1$.

Comment: There is nothing special about keeping 0 and excluding 1, as was mentioned before it is just a convention. We could have called the glued point 1 and excluded 0 instead and everything would be the same. The important point is that after we have glued the two points together we must remember that they are now a single point and so we call it by one of the original points' names.

Comment: That helps. The other noteworthy confusion is this: The unit circle is the closed interval from 0 to 1. Why the is the distance |x-y| <1?

Comment: It is not the closed interval $[0,1]$, but that interval with $0$ and $1$ identified with each other, in other words glued together. Since now $1$ is not in that circle, any two points have a distance between them strictly smaller than $1$. Note that this is necessary for $d$ to be a metric, as I commented on your question.

Comment: The closed interval [0,1] has an intuitive length of 1, but by gluing 1 and 0 together when we choose points x = 0 and y = 1 then x = y and so the distance between these points is 0. If we choose and point close to but strictly less than 1, e,g, y = 0.99999999 then the distance from y to 0 is intuitively y - 0 = 0.99999999. So we can find points which are almost distance 1 apart, but never equal to 1.

Comment: However that is applying an intuitive idea of distance on the interval. But in the cirlce as we pass round it we start to get closer to 0 again, this is why we define the metric d. Let x = 0, then as y increases in distance around the circle it gets 'further' from x until it hits halfway (draw a circle and see what I mean) then it gets closer again. This is why the useful metric here is the one defined in the question, since the distance from 0 increases to 1/2 and then decreases again to zero and y goes from 1/2 to 1. This is what the min{} is all about.

Comment: I really recommend doodling on paper and thinking about why this use of metric makes sense, this kind of thing is always confusing at first but once you get it you'll be really well set up to tackle the next parts of topology.

Comment: @EHH I think I've gotten an intuition of what is going on. This is really like the order of a cyclic group. If the order of the group is n and the element in the group is G, then, at $g^{n}$ we have $g^{n}=e$ which returns the element to the starting point. Thus, the group really is $G={e,g^{2},....,g^{n-1}}$

Comment: Yes that is a good way of thinking of it!